# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no JSON input found while trying google calendar Api in java

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I downloaded google calendar api sample from http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/calendar-cmdline-sample/?repo=samples and created a project in eclipse.
Now when i try to run the project am getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no JSON input found` at this line

```
 FileCredentialStore credentialStore = new FileCredentialStore(
        new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/calendar.json"), JSON_FACTORY);
```

Have any of you tried this example? what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

This error can be resolved by providing input to the .credentials/calendar.json file. If you manually provided the following entry in the calendar.json , it will work :

```
{
  "installed": {
    "client_id": "client_id",
    "client_secret": "client_secret"
  }
}
```

It seems to be the Windows problem which is not allowing to set writable permissions on calendar.json file . The method setWritable(boolean,boolean) is returning false and so is the cause of this problem. Still providing json input manually is not a perfect solutions but your application will work.

Answer (score 0):

That may happen when your application executed before and it created empty .credentials/calendar.json file in you home dir. That may happen if you're running your application in Windows, cause FileCredentialStore tries to do:
file.setReadable(false, false)
and fails.

To solve it just remove calendar.json. Although you might have another error: [unable to set file permissions]
which I don't know how to solve yet.

Answer (score -1):

Is that project having calendar.json resource file. Please share complete exception stack trace.
**Seems some required configuration missed from calendar.json file**

Comment: file calendar.json is empty:(